# Jupyter Notebook NameError when calling function

Tags: python

For one of my classes we are using Juypter to make graphs and all that good stuff. Coding is not my thing, and I usually try to follow my instuctor, but I don't think he's got Juypter down. We are trying to add letters to a chart. Here's the command we were given (I did add the numbers to the cell above):

```
plt.scatter(spectralClass, apparentMagnitude)
plt.title('H-R Diagram Cluster A')
plt.xlabel('Spectral Class')
plt.xticks( (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), ('B', 'A', 'F', 'G', 'K', 'M', '') )
plt.ylabel('Apparent Magnitude') 
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10,10)
plt.show()
```

**I keep getting this error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-385bd2daa1cd> in <module>()
----> 1 plt.scatter(spectralClass, apparentMagnitude)
      2 plt.title('H-R Diagram Cluster A')
      3 plt.xlabel('Spectral Class')
      4 plt.xticks( (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), ('B', 'A', 'F', 'G', 'K', 'M', '') )
      5 plt.ylabel('Apparent Magnitude')

NameError: name 'apparentMagnitude' is not defined
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlfow. First: Your title is not very helpful and gives not much information about the problem. Second: Regarding your problem: The variable apparentMagnitude is not set, it should have been somewhere in the code before, so the error probably lies there somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in appar**a**ntMagnitude in *IN[66]*

Comment: Aye- I was getting upset at knowing what I was doing wrong! Thank you so much!

Comment: Happens. If that was all, you should marks the answer as correct to "close" the question. Have fun!